# Can't type into password input field using Materialize 1.0.0 in Firefox

Tags: css, forms, firefox, passwords, materialize

When I set focus on the password field inside a form, the `active` class is added to the `label` tag, but is automatically removed and **I can't type into the field**. This happens in Firefox (64.0) but not on Chrome (71.0.3578.98).

Here's the html of the form:

```
<form id="signup-form">
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="email" id="signup-email" required />
    <label for="signup-email">Email address</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input type="password" id="signup-password" required />
    <label for="signup-password">Choose password</label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

## EDIT: add full snippet

Here's a more complete code sample (you may want to look at it in full page mode), both the login and signup modal forms have his issue:

```js
// setup materialize components
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  M.Modal.init(modals);

  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
  M.Collapsible.init(items);

});
```

```html
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <title>Game Guides</title>

</head>

<body class="grey lighten-3">

  <!-- NAVBAR -->
  <nav class="z-depth-0 grey lighten-4">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">

      </a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li class="logged-in">
          <a href="#" class="grey-text modal-trigger" data-target="modal-account">Account</a>
        </li>
        <li class="logged-in">
          <a href="#" class="grey-text" id="logout">Logout</a>
        </li>
        <li class="logged-in">
          <a href="#" class="grey-text modal-trigger" data-target="modal-create">Create Guide</a>
        </li>
        <li class="logged-out">
          <a href="#" class="grey-text modal-trigger" data-target="modal-login">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="logged-out">
          <a href="#" class="grey-text modal-trigger" data-target="modal-signup">Sign up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- SIGN UP MODAL -->
  <div id="modal-signup" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Sign up</h4><br />
      <form id="signup-form">
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="email" id="signup-email" required />
          <label for="signup-email">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="password" id="signup-password" required class="validate" />
          <label for="signup-password">Choose password</label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- LOGIN MODAL -->
  <div id="modal-login" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Login</h4><br />
      <form id="login-form">
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="email" id="login-email" required />
          <label for="login-email">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="password" id="login-password" required />
          <label for="login-password">Your password</label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ACCOUNT MODAL -->
  <div id="modal-account" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content center-align">
      <h4>Account details</h4><br />
      <div class="account-details"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- CREATE GUIDE MODAL -->
  <div id="modal-create" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Create Guide</h4><br />
      <form id="create-form">
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="text" id="title" required>
          <label for="title">Guide Title</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
          <textarea id="content" class="materialize-textarea" required></textarea>
          <label for="content">Guide Content</label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0">Create</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- GUIDE LIST -->
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <ul class="collapsible z-depth-0 guides" style="border: none;">
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">Guide title</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">Guide title</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body white"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">Guide title</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body white"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">Guide title</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body white"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
  </script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I checked your code with materialize and firefox 64 and there was no problem to type in the field. please use code snippet or jsfiddle to upload your code. so everyone could see what is the problem.

Comment: Thanks @bahmanparsamanesh, I added a code snippet.

Comment: It fixed itself. It's frustrating.

Comment: Yes. It works correctly here. Maybe another reason causes to prevent typing in fields. for example conflict between js libraries